# ideviceinstaller -l won't show the app list on the iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, appium, appium-ios

I'm using `Appium` to test apps on the real device, and I got an strange error, here is the log

> [debug] [iOS] App is not installed. Will try to install.
>
> [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Installing com.Sosgps.BiaoZhun4 failed
>       at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/node-idevice/main.js:159:6
>       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:193:7)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
>       at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
>       at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
>       at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)

[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 1535 ms - 175

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

then I use "ideviceinstaller -l" command to show the app list on the iPhone and I got "Could not connect to lockdownd. Exiting.". Then I open the iTunes and found that the app list is empty

Thanks for your time

**PS:** I have reinstall ideviceinstaller and Xcode and restart my mac and iPhone several times

Comment: did you enable uiautomation on the device? this looks like a permission problem

Answer (score 2):

Get the latest libimobiledevice, which has a fix for this particular issue:

```
brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew link --overwrite libimobiledevice
brew install ideviceinstaller
brew link --overwrite ideviceinstaller
```

Answer (score 0):

*First step:* you need to change Appium setting on dashboard,don't select Full Reset button, and insert your Application path to AppPath context.

*Second:* Check your real Phone whether it has been installed with App or not, if you have then Uninstall it. If not then leave it as it is.